# kivy app shows black screen on android phone

Tags: python, android

The kivy app that I have coded up won't work on my samsung galaxy s10e but will work on my computer. Maybe I need to add somthing to my .spec file but I dont know

Here is the code for the app:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random
class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()


    def generate_number(self):
        self.random_label.text = str(random.randint(0, 1000))



class randomnumber(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()

randomint = randomnumber()
randomint.run()
```